# Adjust font size depending on rows in a table

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to automatically to adjust the font size of the cells depending the numbers of rows? As you can see I have used 100% of width and height. Now I like to increase the font size depending the numbers of rows (number of rows can be vary).

For example:

```
   <table style="height:100%; width:100%" border="1">
     <tr>
        <th> Field 1 </th>
        <th> Field 2 </th>
        <th> Field 3 </th>
        <th> Field 4 </th>
     </tr>

     <tr> 
       <td> One </td>
       <td> Two </td>
       <td> Three </td>
       <td> Four </td>
     </tr>

     <tr> 
       <td> One </td>
       <td> Two </td>
       <td> Three </td>
       <td> Four </td>
     </tr>

     <tr> 
       <td> One </td>
       <td> Two </td>
       <td> Three </td>
       <td> Four </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Would you like to increase the `font-size` of `all` your rows?

Comment: @D4V1D Yes Thats right apart from `<th>`

Comment: Try using em values in font-size.

Comment: @stanze This would change the size of the text depending on the size of the window, not on the number of rows.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back If you are happy with one of the answers, could you please accept one?

Answer (score 3):

As per OP's comments:

> Basically it should decrease if more more rows expanding, and increase if less rows.

Here's **one** solution:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var nbRows = $('table').find('tr').length;
    var fontSize;
    switch(nbRows)
    {
        case 1: fontSize = 25;
            break;
        case 2: fontSize = 20;
            break;
        case 3: fontSize = 15;
            break;
        case 4: fontSize = 10;
            break;
        // and so on..
    }
    $('table').find('tr > td').css('font-size', fontSize + 'px');
});
```

I admit there must have some cleaner way of doing so. This was the first one popping in my mind.

---

**Edit**

Something like so, maybe:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var nbRows = $('table').find('tr').length;
    var factor = 100; // choose number that suits you best
    $('table').find('tr > td').css('font-size', 1 / nbRows * factor + 'px');
});
```

At least, this would handle any possible number of rows.

Comment: I think too but it's must be possible to correlate both `nbRows` and `fontSize` in order to get rid of the `switch()` statement.

Comment: Ah Javascript, I don't like the idea I have to include the number of nbRows and specify the font size. I think better option to include math formula to work out the number of rows and font size?

Comment: I dont think it is working properly, the more rows you have, it increase the font largely and created a scrollbar.  basically it should decrease if more more rows expanding, and increase if less rows.

Comment: You'd have @enyce12 pure `CSS` solution but if you want jQuery, I'll work on this one.

Comment: @D4V1D yea you can fix your jQuery :)

Comment: I've edited my second code. Feel free to test it on your HTML `<table>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure CSS solution:

```
/* default */
table tr {
    font-size: 20px;
}

/* one item */
table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    font-size: 32px;
}

/* two items */
table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ tr {
    font-size: 24px;
}

/* three items */
table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ tr {
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* four items */
table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ tr {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd523r68/)

You could easily extend the selectors by any amount you like.

**EDIT**

If you need a more generic version you could also work with a loop (assumed you're using Sass or something similar):

```
$rowsToGenerate: 20;
$factor: 5;
$maxFontSize: 64px;
$minFontSize: 12px;

@for $i from 1 through $rowsToGenerate {
  @if($i == 1) {
    /* one item */
    table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}) {
        font-size: $maxFontSize;
    }
  } @else {
    $fontSize: $maxFontSize - ($i * $factor);

    /* multiple items */
    table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}),
    table tr:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}) ~ tr {
      @if($fontSize < $minFontSize){
        font-size: $minFontSize;
      } @else {
        font-size: $fontSize;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/4dc0e5f073078ec7dbea)

Comment: Not bad, but it would be better to detect number of rows and calculate the font size like @D4V1D answer, can it be done in CSS or CSS3?

Comment: Detecting the current number of rows is not possible. You can however predefine the styles for several rows. I've updated my answer with a more automated Sass version of it.

Comment: Thank you, `font-size: $i * $factor;` shouldn't that be decrease when more rows added.

Comment: Yes, I've made an error in reasoning. See my updated my answer.

Comment: `minFontSize` also required here :)

Comment: @vp_arth Updated it ;)